# React express get request not sending data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, express

Hwy guys. I have set up an endpoint on a local server for my react application. I attempt to make a get endpoint in which I send the data of the result to the requester. It seems that i get no data sent to any client requesting from this end-point. At the end of my code I send result.data which basicly should be returning the whole  list of users coming from my database.

```
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {

  db.query("SELECT id, name, username, phonenr FROM users;", 

  (err, result) => {
    if (err)  {
      res.send({err: err}) //Sending error to front-end
      console.log(err);
   }
   if (result.length>0) {
     res.send(result.data); //Sending list of users
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Have you ever successfully implemented an Express endpoint before?

Comment: Yes. Works with a post-request fx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to the issue.

Seemed that i should not send (result.data) but instead just the (result)

Answer (score 0):

Log the `result` variable for better understanding. Also, you forgot the else block if `result.length` is `0`.

Comment: I did log it. It returned "undefined". This is my issue. I cant understand why its not reading the result from the database query